# how to centralize error handling based on results in .net 7?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, exception

I used to have exceptions in my control flow and I can easily write a middleware to add problem details to the response. But now I am using FleuntResults and don't know how I can achieve previous behavior.

I wanna get rid of below code for each controller action :

```
 if (result.IsFailed)
    {
        var errorMessage = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.Message;

        var details = new ProblemDetails()
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound,
            Title = "The specified resource was not found.",
            Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
            Detail = errorMessage 
        };

        return NotFound(details);
    }
```

Code sample with exceptions :

```
switch (exception)
    {
        case NotFoundException notFoundException:
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

                var response = new NotFoundResponseBody(notFoundException.Message);
                var payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response);
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload);
            }
        default:
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                var response = new { message = exception.Message };
                var payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(response);
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(payload);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults/wiki/Returning-Result-Objects-from-ASP.NET-Core-Controller).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I don't understand how I can use it. Documentation seems a bit off. I don't see an option to customize ProblemDetails there

Comment: I don't know either. But I had a quick look [here](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults) and it offered some documentation for what you are asking. Currently it's only a preview feature. There is also a related GitHub [issue](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults/issues/149) where you could ask for help.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride looks like it is not ready yet. I tried to write my custom middleware but the code there is too complex and I think it is an overkill. But I still wanna learn how you handle this kinda operations in general? doesn't matter if we use FluentResults package or custom Result pattern implementation

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults/issues/170) from the same repository if that is what you are using with somewhat of an idea. Especially notice the authors carefully worded "I have to invest my time wisely." Do the same is your time wisely invested in that package?